# DSE sqoop can't import date SQL Server to Cassandra table

Tags: java, cassandra

Currently I have downloaded datastax enterprise edition 4.0 and used dse sqoop migrate SQL Server to Cassandra I am getting the following error:

ERROR:

```
sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:653)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:542)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:565)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:178)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:262)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1060)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:82)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:390)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:57)
```

I have put the sqljdbc4.jar file in the below paths

```
/usr/share/dse/sqoop/lib
/usr/share/dse/hadoop/lib
```

Still I am getting above error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried placing the jar in /usr/share/dse/sqoop?